# fancybox not showing popup photos

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox, gallery

I have this fancybox gallery

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center gap-4 mt-lg-5">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center gap-3">
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/Rectangle 35.png">
                        <img src="/img/Rectangle 35.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/Rectangle 35.png">
                        <img src="/img/Rectangle 35.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/Rectangle 35.png">
                        <img src="/img/Rectangle 35.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/Rectangle 35.png">
                        <img src="/img/Rectangle 35.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/Rectangle 35.png">
                        <img src="/img/Rectangle 35.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/Rectangle 15 big.png">
                        <img src="/img/Rectangle 15 big.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

problem is that when I click on the first image, it displays correctly, but if I click pictures other than first, it does not(on first click).
but if resize the window, or after clicking first image just click another one, it displays just fine, why should that be problem? I thought it was because of conflict but I have latest fancyapps included, like this:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css"
/>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.umd.js" defer></script>

 <script>
       

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

            Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', {
            Slideshow: {
                progressParentEl: (slideshow) => {
                    return slideshow.instance.container;
                }
            }
        }); 
      

});
    </script>
```

and I can not figure out why, any ideas?
see the problem here:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it is not possible to help you without seeing your page/demo. Fancybox itself works fine.

Comment: hey, thanks for your feedback, I know who you are !!!  on top of my css file I had *{transition: all 0.4s ease;} , because that is my default, once I deleted that line,fancybox started working just fine.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Avoid using global CSS rules as it may affect any 3rd part script.